# Store Records without keys in mongodb or document mapping with keys

Tags: mongodb, nosql

mongodb always stores records in such a way that

{
 '_id' : '1' ,
'name' : 'nidhi'
}

But i want to store in a way like

{ 123 , 'nidhi'}

I do not want to store keys again and again in database.

Is it possible with mongodb or with any other database.

Is there anything like sql is possible in nosql that I set the architecture first like mysql and then start inserting values in documents.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with MongoDB. Documents are defined by Key/Value pairs. That has something to do that [BSON (Binary JSON)](http://bsonspec.org) – the internal storage format of MongoDB – was developed from [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](http://www.json.org). And without keys, you couldn't query the database at all, except by rather awkward positional parameters.

However, if disk space is so precious, you could revise your modeling to sth like:

```
{  _id:1,
   values:['nidhi','foo','bar','baz']
}
```

However, since disk space is relatively cheap when compared to computing power (not a resource MongoDB uses a lot, though) and RAM (rule of thumb for MongoDB: the more, the better), you approach doesn't make sense. For a REST API to return a record to the client, all you have to do is (pseudo code):

```
var docToReturn = collection.findOne({_id:requestedId});

if(docToReturn){

  response.send(200,docToReturn);

} else {

  response.send(404,{'state':404,'error':'resource '+requestedId+' not available'});

}
```

Even if the data was possible to query with your approach, you would have to map the returned values to meaningful keys. And how would you deal with the fact that Arrays don't have a guaranteed order? Or with the fact that MongoDB has dynamic schemas, so that one doc in the collection may have a totally different structure than the other?

Comment: Yaa I knew it but is there anything like sql is possible  in nosql that I set the architecture first like mysql and then start inserting values in documents .

Comment: And how should that work with the nondeterministic order of arrays? And the _dynamic_ schema? One document can be `{_id:1,foo:"Hello"}` whereas the next may look like `{_id:"config.admins",users:[{"name":Nidhi Sen","email":"foo@bar.com"},{"googleId":"abcdef","userAdminOnly":true}]}`? I wouldn't care about disk space so much. Actually, disk space is so cheap that the time spending here and thinking about it most likely is more expensive than increasing it.

Comment: I will handle deterministic and nondeterministic and I am not doing this for saving disk space but i want this for saving my code. actually i dnt want to write keys again and again in my database.

Comment: I don't get your use case, but you got your answer ;). It is not possible with MongoDB. So maybe you should use a RDBMS, if that fit's you use case better.

Comment: :) okay I will search for any other database. may be it is possible with any other database.

Comment: I doubt that. Storing data in a DBMS is all about storing relations between keys and values. But please let us know your findings.

Comment: okay i will let you know when i will successfully found my goal.